# Java Error- Java Could Not Load the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, jvm, bluej

I was typing a program and this error occured:

BlueJ was unable to create a Java Virtual Machine(VM) to execute projects.This is a serious problem-you will not be able to create objects or execute methods till it is fixed.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling BlueJ.How do I fix this?

Comment: Is BlueJ pointing to a valid JDK installation?

Comment: Have you installed a JVM?

Comment: no.but it was working fine till this morning.

Comment: @aqua Did you google your problem? It has [a page on the BlueJ FAQ](http://www.bluej.org/help/faq.html#socket-exc)

Comment: I did google it.It said that there was a problem with the firewall but it is still not working even when i turned the firewall off.

Comment: @aqua Go to BlueJ setting and check if the JDK directory is valid.

Comment: @BackSlash It is valid, I checked

Comment: Try reinstalling your JDK and JVM.

Comment: Can you check if your disk is mounted fine or if there's some change in the mount point ? Try running a helloWorld in java to be sure. Also check for user level permissions

Answer (score 1):

As the FAQ of BlueJ suggests you probably dont java  JDK installed. 
First go get it from [here](http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/)
(or directly from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index-jsp-138363.html) if you want the latest version which I recommend to you).

If the problem still exists after the installation you probably have to set/ create the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` and include it to your environment variable PATH. You will be able to find a broad spectrum on how to do this by searching it on google.